# Extract value from NSObject key/value pair

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsobject

I have a NSObject variable which represents something like :

```
{objectID : 2, name : John Doe, url : www.test.com }
```

I want to extract only the url from the NSObject variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please add some more information about your question.
The representation that you provide here looks like a json string and you want to get value of url?
Do you want to parse the json?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: The above is not an "NSObject".  Nor is it valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use

```
[myObj valueForKey:@"url"]
```